# Complex Java Regular Expression with Nested Groupings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression written that will capture what I'm trying to match in Java, but can't seem to get it.

This is my latest attempt:

```
Pattern.compile( "[A-Za-z0-9]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*/?" );
```

This is what I want to match:

- `hello`
- `hello/world`
- `hello/big/world`
- `hello/big/world/`

This what I don't want matched:

- `/`
- `/hello`
- `hello//world`
- `hello/big//world`

I'd appreciate any insight into what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: Can you show us how you are using this regex? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: With your current regex there is no way to find `/` `hello//world` `hello/big//world` so I can only assume that you are having problem with `/hello`. I am guessing that while finding match you get as result `hello` part from `/hello` which shouldn't happen. If that is the case you can add this `(?<![\\w/])` at start of your regex. This is called [negative-look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) and it makes sure that match will not have any character from `\w` class or `/`. It is just hunch and we all would be glad if you add more details about your problem

Comment: @Pshemo - The OP's regex won't match `/hello`

Comment: @sln yes, but if OP will use `find` he will get `hello` part which may not be what (s)he want.

Comment: Well, then he needs anchors or the nagative behind assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
Pattern.compile( "^[A-Za-z0-9]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*/?$" );
```

Comment: Starting ^ and ending $ are redundant when used with `matches` (which OP *should* be using).

Comment: True it is not needed in `matches()` method but since question is about regex it is better to be explicit I guess.

Comment: With Pshemo's input, OP's error may precisely be in the way he is *using* the regex instead of in the regex itself.

Comment: That's the reason I didn't assume `matches()` is being used here.

Comment: That's the reason we should help OP use `matches` instead of fixing his regex :P

Comment: Sure I can suggest only based on the information presented. At present information presented is regex and question is also tagged as regex. If & when I see more info I will edit (or even delete) my answer.

Comment: So it turns out that was the issue.  The ^ and $ are required when using a Matcher, but not when using Pattern.matches - I figured it was something subtle I was missing.  Many thanks!!

Comment: @user3241719 `Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string); m.matches();`---you don't need ^ and $ with the Matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your regex require question mark at the end?

I always write unit tests for my regexes so I can fiddle with them until they pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
// your exact regex:
final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( "[A-Za-z0-9]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*/?" );

// your exact examples:
final String[]
    good = { "hello", "hello/world", "hello/big/world", "hello/big/world/" },
    bad = { "/", "/hello", "hello//world", "hello/big//world"};

for (String goodOne : good) System.out.println(regex.matcher(goodOne).matches());
for (String badOne : bad) System.out.println(!regex.matcher(badOne).matches());
```

prints a solid column of `true` values.

Put another way: your regex is perfectly fine just as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to 'Capture' is being overwritten each quantified itteration.  Just change parenthesis arangement.

```
  #  "[A-Za-z0-9]+((?:/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)/?"

 [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
 (                                  # (1 start)
      (?: / [A-Za-z0-9]+ )*
 )                                  # (1 end)
 /?
```

Or, with no capture's at all  -

```
 #  "[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9]+)*/?"

 [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
 (?: / [A-Za-z0-9]+ )*
 /?
```